# How to create 2 full screen columns, the first with responsive image and the second with text

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I try to build a page with 2 columns. The first one I want to take the 70% of screen and the other column take 20%.

In the first column I try to put a responsive image using css or script but nothing satisfy my eye.

Have you any idea?

example: http://www.screencast.com/t/0SddrUSln5

Some techniques followed:

1. Bootstrap...

   ```
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-10">
       <img src="img/intro_img.jpg" alt="" style="width:100%;">
   </div>

   <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-2">
   sidebar
   </div>
   ```
2. Full screen jQuery script

   http://blog.aaronvanderzwan.com/2012/07/maximage-2-0/

   But I can't figure out how to generate a sidebar that "push" the full screen image and do not οverlapping.
3. Class "responsive-img"

   Τhe picture never fills 70% ορ 80% of the screen and a very thin white margin exists at the bottom. Actually in the 83,67....% When it goes 84% scroll bar appears so no full screen column.

Comment: Would you please share with us the code you created and we will be glad to help out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your asking....  But if you want to set the width of a div to only take up 20% of the screen you can use this:

```
 #div{
width: 20%
}
```

then just make a div tag with the id of div and it will take up 20% of the screen.

Is this what your asking?